# Where is the Tan function?

Tags: delphi, trigonometry

I want to make a projectile motion calculator, but I noticed that `tan` is not declared, even though `sin` and `cos` are.

[Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Tan) tells me that it should be declared, but I don't see it.

Where is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [in the *Math* unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Tan), just like the page you cite says. (Look in the upper right corner of the page.)

`Sin` and `Cos` are defined in the *System* unit because they're assembler system calls, whereas `Tan` is classically implemented as simply *sin* θ / *cos* θ. Nowadays, `Tan` is implemented in assembler as well, but since it was originally defined in the *Math* unit, that's where it continues to reside.

Answer (score 2):

try Math.Tan or add Math to your uses clause.